# How to correctly get cookies from website?

Tags: java, parsing, heroku, cookies

I have code that correctly receives cookies from the site and saves it in a file when I run it from the integrated development environment:

```
String url = "https://www.avito.ru";
Map<String, String> cookies = Jsoup.connect(url).execute().cookies();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file));
out.writeObject(cookies);
System.out.println("Get cookies from: " + url + " and write into: " + file.getName());
System.out.println(cookies);
out.close();
```

But when I upload and run it on the Heroku server (but at this time I temporarily store cookies in the handler object), I get an error in the logs.
It occurs at the step .execute ().
Heroku code:

```
try {
       Map <String, String> cookies = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                    .execute()
                                    .cookies();
       cookieHandler.setAvitoCookies(cookies);
       System.out.println("> AVITO COOKIE:" + cookies); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Heroku error log:

```
org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=https://www.avito.ru
```

Is there any solution to get cookies properly?

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `HttpStatusException` because the server returned a 403 status code. If you want to read the cookies from error responses (4xx - 5xx status codes) add [`ignoreHttpErrors(true)`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/Connection.html#ignoreHttpErrors-boolean-) method:

```
Map <String, String> cookies = Jsoup.connect(url)
                                    .ignoreHttpErrors(true)
                                    .execute()
                                    .cookies();
```

Comment: Now there is no exception but cookies map is still empty.

Comment: Which means there are no cookies when you get 403 response. You should be able to debug this in a web browser.

Comment: It seem that I found solution. Need to add in code line: `.proxy(String ip , int port)`

Comment: It would imply your network is behind a proxy, this is however completely different problem than what you asked.